# Basic Horizontal Menu not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble with getting a simple horizontal navigation to work/look nice on the iPad. This is just a straight horizontal menu, no dropdowns, so there is no need to worry about the a:hover (I know it doesn't work on mobile).

The site has twitter bootstrap, jQuery and jQuery UI. The menu is not a main navigation, but a tabbed menu to for allowing people to filter data in a table (clicking the option causes it to hit a rest call to get new data)

On the desktop, it shows the menu bar. On the iPad, it shows the UL listing. I am hoping to have this fixed for stylizing. The reason I am not using the Bootstrap option is because I need the menu to stay the whole time

**CSS**

```
ul.horizontalNav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

ul.horizontalNav li {
    float: left;
}

ul.horizontalNav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.horizontalNav li a:hover {
    background-color: #999;
}

ul.horizontalNav li.active {
    background-color:#4CAF50;
}

ul.horizontalNav li {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

ul.horizontalNav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

ul.horizontalNav li {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

ul.horizontalNav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="CAFSummaryHeaderBar"> 
    <ul class="horizontalNav" id="CAFSummaryMenu">
        <li><a href="#All">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#MyRequests">My Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Draft">Drafts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Review">In Admin Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Approval">Getting Approvals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#FollowUp">Follow Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Archived">Archived</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Abandoned">Abandoned</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use media queries for your css then?

eg:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```

Then just add desired styles within like

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
      /* For landscape layouts only */
ul.mylist {
my: style;
}

}
```